# How to add multiple values via prompt to textarea without removing and changing other texts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prompt

I created this fiddle so that you can see the struggle I have.

My HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form" name="my-form-name">

<button class="html-button">Link me</button>

<textarea name="x" id="post-text" rows="17" required="required"></textarea>

<button type="submit" class="submit-button-form">submit form</button>

</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".html-button").on("click", function () {
    var urls = prompt("Add a link", "http://");
    var setText = $("#post-text").val(urls);
// Adding prompt text into my input field
    $("#post-text").val(urls);
                            });
```

This code works, but it only works once. Meaning: if I add a hyperlink it works the first time, but when I want to add **another** link, it doesn't insert it. Instead, it just changes whatever I had put in first + the additonal plain text I am adding to the textarea.

**My question:** how can I make this link addition independent of what I type in the textarea (plain text) and make sure that I can add more links without it changing the other ones in the textarea?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxqsztj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append data instead of replacing

```
$("#post-text").val(urls);   <-- here you're replacing data with url only
```

instead you need to add previous text along with url

```
var setText = $("#post-text").val(urls);
$("#post-text").val(setText + urls);   <-- adding url along with previous value
```

```js
$(".html-button").on("click", function() {
  var urls = prompt("Add a link", "http://");
  var setText = $("#post-text").val();
  // Adding prompt text into my input field
  $("#post-text").val(setText + urls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" role="form" name="my-form-name">
  <button class="html-button" type='button'>Link me</button>
  <textarea name="x" id="post-text" rows="17" required="required"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="submit-button-form">submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It works, partially. The problem is: now it directly submits the form after clicking on "OK" button in the prompt... is that something we can fix?

Comment: Rephrasing: it only submits the form after pressing enter when the prompt is being shown... is that something we can fix?

Comment: @Siyah but in your fiddle there's no `form` tag at all ?

Comment: Yes, so maybe I was not clear enough. The textarea is part of a form. I'll edit my HTML so that you can see what I mean. I didn't think that that would be a problem, so that's why. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Siyah you need to add type attribute to button to stop auto submission, check the updated code

Comment: Awesome! That was easy... yet easy to miss. Thank you, Code Maniac!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are resetting the value of the *textarea* in the following line with the current prompt value:

```
var setText = $("#post-text").val(urls);
```

You can use jQuery's [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to insert content in the textarea.

You can remove that and add newline (`\n`) in each click to appear each link in separate line like the following way:

```js
$(".html-button").on("click", function () {
  var urls = prompt("Add a link", "http://");
  $("#post-text").append(urls + '\n');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="html-button">Link me</button>

<textarea name="x" id="post-text" rows="17" required="required"></textarea>
```

Comment: Same problem here. It works to some extent; it keeps submitting the form when pressing enter while the prompt is there. Can we prevent that?